# How to format integers greater than 999 in python to look more readable?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of numbers that I want to print to the user. Each number is greater than one million so I want to print it as 1.000.000 or 1,000,000 (any of these forms is valid to me). I want to know if is it possible to format integer numbers this way in python using the built-in formating utilities.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`locale.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.format). You will need to `setlocale` first, since the formatting style is dependent on location (European countries typically use `.` instead of `,` for separating the digits, for instance).

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'English_United Kingdom.1252'
>>> locale.format("%d", 1000000000, grouping=True)
'1,000,000,000'
```

`LC_ALL` sets the locale to the default, usually in the `LANG` environment variable.

Comment: Notice that this is standard British usage - "European" doesn't include UK.  That strip of water makes a big difference!

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.1 you can use the [thousands format specifier](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.1.html#pep-378-format-specifier-for-thousands-separator):

```
>>> ',.2f'.format(1234567.89)
'1,234,567.89'
```

Comment: This feature is a bit incomplete, as it doesn't consider alternate formats such as the common `.` instead of `,`.

Comment: True. The docs do discuss that a bit, and there are plans to make it more complete in future versions.